# Acceleration - how to reset value while key not pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a little 2d game set into the space and I was making the script for move the ship this is a part of the code:

```
public float acceleration;
public float maxSpeed;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*acceleration, Space.Self);
        if (acceleration < maxSpeed) acceleration += 0.1F;
```

Now, as you can see there are no errors in the code, but this is not the problem, I want to reset the value of "acceleration" to 0 when the key "W" isn't pressed but I have no idea of how I can do it.

Comment: Add an else statement?

Comment: I tried with

else if (!Input.getKet(KeyCode.W)) {
}   but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys i resolved on my own..

this is the code if anybody wants to know

```
void Update () {

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * shipSpeed, Space.Self);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        if (shipSpeed < maxSpeed) shipSpeed += 0.1F;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (shipSpeed > 0) shipSpeed -= 0.1F; 
    }
```

PS: i renamed acceleration to shipSpeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Input.GetKeyUp to detect button has been released

```
   if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        //W key released reset acceleration to zero
    }
```